# Language template per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization

I've got a Rails application in which we want to change the wording depending on a profile the user picks so that it's suited to them. It's all in english but just different wording. For instance some people call 'Suppliers', 'creditors' or 'vendors' depending on if they are accountants or not.

I was thinking of something like this

- User has one profile
- Profile has many users
- Profile has many words

Problem with this is I would have to make sure that in the words table I have the same set of words for each profile. eg:

```
Words table
| profile_id | Name     | Value    |
|------------+----------+----------|
| 1          | creditor | customer |
| 2          | creditor | creditor |
| 3          | creditor | supplier |
```

Where the profile table maybe

```
Profiles
| ID | Name             |
|----+------------------|
|  1 | Service Industry |
|  2 | Accountant       |
|  3 | Basic            |
```

Update:

Later down the track I also plan to use i18n in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're not going to make this a multilingual app, you may want to just leverage the existing i18n system (which supports fallback to a default locale for each term).  You could define a 'Service Industry' locale, an 'Accountant' locale, etc. and have the default locale ('en') contain all of the terms.

This also wouldn't require database hits.  Assuming the terms are reasonably static, that's an advantage.  If you're frequently changing the custom terms, then this might not be a good approach.

Comment: I will want to include i18n support down the track

Comment: You can actually still use this approach, even if you're going multilingual.  You can use 'regional' locales, which are locales that are subdivisions of language.  Even better, that means you can essentially define a default term per language, and the fallback will just work.  See here (http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) and search for regional for details.

Comment: This has worked out well, thank you. I've added en.yml, en-basic.yml and it.yml now and it all works even with my AngularJS templates